# How to move a button programmatically in an absolute layout

Tags: android, adt, absolutelayout

i make a test application in eclipse with adt plugin. I want when a button is clicked to move it in a random position in the screen, i found some example around the internet by nothing works

```
Button noBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NoBtn);
noBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Button noBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NoBtn);
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams OBJ=new
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(35,35,408,160);
    noBtn.setLayoutParams(OBJ);
}
});
```

and i get application error

Comment: I was using RlativeLayout in the xml. So i change it `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams OBJ=newRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 80); 
    OBJ.topMargin = randomHeight;
    int a = ApplicationUtils.getScreenHeight( getWindowManager());
    int aa = ApplicationUtils.getScreenWidth( getWindowManager());
    OBJ.leftMargin = randomWidth;
    noBtn.setLayoutParams(OBJ);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using the layoutparam in android, u can specify the position of your widget through the java code rather than specifying it in the xml file in android.

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams OBJ = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(35,35,408,160);
button.setLayoutParams(OBJ);
```

here-

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,X-position,Y-position)
```

is what i have specified as (35,35,408,160)